# How to append parquet file with old schema to new parquet file having new schema

Tags: hadoop, parquet, avro

1. Our current project create individual parquet file to save record on hdfs file system with avro schema.
2. There is another process which run every four hours, it took such individual parquet files and create new aggregate parquet file out of them and remove all processed individual files
3. This is working fine. But when new column is added as part of release in avro scheme then aggregation job is failing, as parquet file append operation is failing for invidual parquet file created with old schema before release.
4. How to resolve this issue?

---

The application code is in java. ParquetFileReader is used to read individual parquet file and ParquetFileWriter is used to create new aggregator parquet file. Both use same avro schema file.

---

```
Java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Missing column 'TEST_NEW_COLUMN', cannot copy row group: BlockMetaData{968,931698 [ColumnMetaData{SNAPPY [CLIENT_REQUEST_ID_COLUMN] OPTIONAL BINARY ...
..
at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.parquetFileWriter.appendRowGroup(ParquetFileWriter.java:541)
~[parquet-hadoop-bundle-1.9.0-cdh6.3.4.java!/:?]
at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader.appendTo(ParquetFileReder.java:676)..
```